# Are shiny odds connected to story completion in Dynamax adventures?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

There is a lot of info out there about shiny odds in the dynamax adventures.

[Screen Rant](https://screenrant.com/pokemon-crown-tundra-shiny-drop-rate-odds-dynamax/), wrote:

> At this time, if the player has all four Pokémon slots filled, the chances of a shiny Pokémon without a shiny charm is 4 in 300, or 1 in 75. However, with the Shiny Charm equipped, the odds are an incredible 4 in 100, meaning 1 in every 25 Pokémon could be shiny.

I've probably done at least 50 dynamax adventures with the shiny charm, but I've yet to come across any shinies.

Are the shiny odds in the dynamax adventures connected to story completion? There are some parts of the story that I have not completed - I'm just wondering if this is holding my odds back or not?

Comment: The math in the article is incorrect.  You can't add probabilities like that, otherwise you would have a 100/100 chance after 100 encounters, which is simply not true.  The actual numbers are fairly close (3.95% and 1.32% of a shiny per adventure), but be wary that you'll never be guaranteed a shiny.  You're just having bad luck.

Comment: Assuming you caught all 4 Pokémon in each of 50 adventures, that's 200 rolls at a shiny. With 1/100 odds, your chance of not getting a shiny after that many is (99/100)^200 = ~13%. Unlucky, but not unusually so.

Answer (score -1):

A few months ago in three Dynamax adventures in a row I found 3 shinies. Since then I've done over 200 Dynamax adventures (I've lost count) and I haven't found anything. I think it's a matter of luck.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! This doesn't actually answer the question, it should be a comment.